# hibernate - One to One mapping, how to get the associated object using annotation?

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I have 2 objects `Customer` and `CustomerAcctSetting`. `CustomerAcctSetting` has a foreign key `CUSTOMER_ID`. My problem is when I get a `Customer` object I can't get the associated `CustomerAcctSetting` and returns only null.

Below are the 2 hibernate object:

**`Customer.java`**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends BaseDomain{
    .
    .
    .
    private CustomerAcctSetting customerAcctSetting;

    @Id
    @Override
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator (name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column (name = "CUSTOMER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    .
    .
    .

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    public CustomerAcctSetting getCustomerAcctSetting() {
        return customerAcctSetting;
    }

    public void setCustomerAcctSetting(CustomerAcctSetting customerAcctSetting) {
        this.customerAcctSetting = customerAcctSetting;
    }
}
```

**`CustomerAcctSetting.java`**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_ACCT_SETTING")
public class CustomerAcctSetting extends BaseDomain{
    private int customerId;
    .
    .
    .

    @Id
    @Override
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator (name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column (name = "CUSTOMER_ACCT_SETTING_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    .
    .
    .

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
}
```

I did not include any mapping for `Customer` in the `CustomerAcctSetting` because I don't have to get `Customer` from `CustomerAcctSetting`. I only put `CUSTOMER_ID` in the `CustomerAcctSetting`.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by usinng `mappedBy="Customer"` in `Customer` and added the `Customer` in `CustomerAcctSetting` and `@JoinColumn`.

Below are the classes:

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends BaseDomain{
    .
    .
    .
    private CustomerAcctSetting customerAcctSetting;

    @Id
    @Override
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator (name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column (name = "CUSTOMER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    .
    .
    .

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer")
    public CustomerAcctSetting getCustomerAcctSetting() {
        return customerAcctSetting;
    }

    public void setCustomerAcctSetting(CustomerAcctSetting customerAcctSetting) {
        this.customerAcctSetting = customerAcctSetting;
    }
}
```

**`CustomerAcctSetting.java`**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_ACCT_SETTING")
public class CustomerAcctSetting extends BaseDomain{
    private Customer customer;
    .
    .
    .

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="CUSTOMER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}
```